# What is the probability that a customer waits for lesser than 3 minutes?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The rate of service is exponential and the service rate is 12 customers served per hour. The arrival of customers is in a Poisson distribution at the rate of 30 per hour. There are 3 servers and the average waiting time is 7 minutes. How would I go about doing this? Could really use some help!

Edit - I've also calculated the probability that an arriving customer has to wait as 0.7. Not sure how to calculate the probability regarding waiting time though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not the total time a customer spends in the system, but just in the line. Do you know the formula for the queue waiting time $\mathcal{W_q}$ distribution of an M/M/3 queue? Its a pretty common formula in queue theory textbooks. Its cumbersome to write, so ill jsut link you to it, see Slide 35 of this [ppt.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGYQFjAI&url=http://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen%2520/ORMM/instruction/powerpoint/or_models_09/14_queuing.ppt&ei=M7t3UoSuJ6feyAGnmYCAAw&usg=AFQjCNERufhZy8x954s9OsgTw9pCJ0QqDA) And p.13 of [this](http://ocw.nctu.edu.tw/upload/classbfs121001554684839.pdf)

Comment: I know the formula for the average waiting time in a queue, that is Wq. I even know Pw, the probability that a customer would have to wait. But I'm not sure how to calculate the probability that a customer would have to wait for a/greater than/lesser than a certain time limit. 

Yeah, what I want is the total time a customer spends waiting in the line before he is served. Formula's not given in my text book.

Comment: See the links I sent you, $P(\mathcal{W_q}>t)$ is in there. Should help you out a lot.

Comment: Just did. Thanks!